# Typescript: Keyword arguments vs positional arguments

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am transitioning a JS app to TS. I don't know TS so would love some of your wisdom!

In the JS app, we used a lot of keyword arguments because they are more descriptive and have no order dependency. This is especially helpful for functions that have a lot of arguments.

However, as I start the switch to TS, it feels like using objects as function arguments is really verbose / ugly no matter which approach I choose. I either have to:

1. Create a interface / type for the arguments and then point to the type which feels like overkill when you have a bunch of private functions

```
interface MyFuncArgs {
  display_as_amount: number;
  amount_to_points_ratio: number;
  amount: number;
  currency: string;
  amount_approved: number;
  status: 'approved' | 'rejected';
}


const renderPaymentCopy = ({
  display_as_amount,
  amount_to_points_ratio,
  amount,
  currency,
  amount_approved,
  status,
}: MyFuncArgs) => {...}
```

2. Type it inline, which makes the function argument list super long

```
const renderPaymentCopy = ({
  display_as_amount,
  amount_to_points_ratio,
  amount,
  currency,
  amount_approved,
  status,
}: {
  display_as_amount: number;
  amount_to_points_ratio: number;
  amount: number;
  currency: string;
  amount_approved: number;
  status: 'approved' | 'rejected';
}) => {
```

3. Name the object argument and type it, and have to destructure it immediately after. Two issues: 1) I need to name my argument object something which is not ideal since it is a combination of all the arguments and doesn't really represent anything nameable 2) I don't do anything with `args` besides destructure it immediately, which feels redundant

```
const renderPaymentCopy = (args: {
  display_as_amount: number;
  amount_to_points_ratio: number;
  amount: number;
  currency: string;
  amount_approved: number;
  status: 'approved' | 'rejected';
}) => {
  const {
    display_as_amount,
    amount_to_points_ratio,
    amount,
    currency,
    amount_approved,
    status,
  } = args;

  ...
};
```

If I switch to positional arguments, although TS provides static typing to prevent some issues that go along with positional arguments (like union types to ensure the value is not a random string), I still feel like going back to positioned arguments would not be bulletproof, and would reintroduce the dependency of ordered unnamed arguments which makes for a bad API.

Consider this example:

```
const renderPaymentCopy = (
  display_as_amount: number;
  amount_to_points_ratio: number;
  amount: number;
  currency: string;
  amount_approved: number;
  status: 'approved' | 'rejected';
) => {...}

renderPaymentCopy(
  100,
  20,
  30,
  'usd',
  40,
  'approved'
)
```

While it's a much terser way of defining a function, It's unclear what each argument stands for. The amount related fields could easily be swapped accidentally.

Therefore, it feels like the code is getting super long with TS. With JS, I got the best of both worlds: no extra lines of code + keyword arguments. However, with TS it feels like I need to make a tradeoff.

Would someone mind enlightening me how it's normally done in the TS world?

Comment: For an object with a bunch of members, I'd think that often times it'd be used in more than one place, in which approach 1 makes for the least amount of repetitive code. Otherwise, approach 2 is just fine IMO - *I don't do anything with args besides destructure it immediately* is a very common approach.

Comment: Is is possible to reduce number of arguments in your function? If it is not - you can stick with forst approach

Answer (score 1):

First, like @CertainPerformance points out - destructuring an object immediately is a common approach.

SOLID principles hold solid ground here (pun intended). `I`nterface Segregation means that you should limit the scope of an interface. `S`ingle Responsibility Principle means that you limit the reasons for a piece of code to change.

As the number of members of an interface goes up - or as the number of parameters passed to a method goes up - you're making the code harder to test, harder to change, harder to read.

I think the short answer to your question is that, in TypeScript:

- You WILL be writing interfaces and types a lot. This slows you down. If you make your methods smaller and accept fewer arguments (ideally fewer than three or four), you probably won't need an interface for everything. You can use primitive types as your arguments which will make your code better.
- Going from JS to TS as a one-to-one translation of code may not be a good idea. Take a look at your architecture and apply SOLID principles.